# Is the origin of giants explained anywhere in Tolkien's fiction, notes or letters?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In *The Hobbit*, there is a brief mention of giants playing games by tossing enormous boulders whilst the twelve dwarves, Gandalf, and Bilbo make their way through a pass in the Misty Mountains.

Where did giants come from? I do not recall them from *The Silmarillion*. Does Tolkien ever address their origins elsewhere?

Comment: As stated in the comments to that question, that one is specifically about the origins of giants.

Comment: @Edlothiad Thank you! I searched and somehow missed that.

Answer (score 3):

In the final published materials they only appear in the Hobbit.  Their only other mention are in older drafts of the Silmarillion/Lord of the Rings, which are either contradicted by later drafts or of at best questionable accuracy regarding the final material.

In early drafts of Lord of the Rings giants were used instead of Ents.

If you go back to the Book of Lost Tales you can find reference to them serving Morgoth.  But this is the earliest writings, you have to be very careful applying any of it to the final product.

Maybe Bilbo made them up in his writings, there isn't outside of the Hobbit to confirm their existence.

I'll dig up quotes for these tomorrow, assuming someone else doesn't find them first.

Comment: Interesting thought about Bilbo making them up. The passage in the hobbit is quite vague and could just be an extended metaphor for how bad the storm was.

Comment: Except that Gandalf later says he should try to find a half decent giant to plug up the entrance to the goblin cave with bouldrs, and there is mention of giants coming into this part of the world in Gandalf's speculation about Beorn's origin.